# large(over 1 million classes) multi-class classifier via Keras

Tags: keras, deep-learning, keras-layer, multiclass-classification

I have data for around 2 million active customers and around 2-5 years worth of transaction data by customer. This data includes features such as what item that customer bought, what store they bought it from, the date they purchased that item, how much they bought, how much they paid, etc.

I need to predict which of our customers will shop in the next 2 weeks.

Right now my data is set up like this

```
item_a  item_b  item_c  item_d  customer_id  visit
dates                                             
6/01       1      0      0      0  cust_123      1
6/02       0      0      0      0  cust_123      0
6/03       0      1      0      0  cust_123      1
6/04       0      0      0      0  cust_123      0
6/05       1      0      0      0  cust_123      1
6/06       0      0      0      0  cust_123      0
6/07       0      0      0      0  cust_123      0
6/08       1      0      0      0  cust_123      1
6/01       0      0      0      0  cust_456      0
6/02       0      0      0      0  cust_456      0
6/03       0      0      0      0  cust_456      0
6/04       0      0      0      0  cust_456      0
6/05       1      0      0      0  cust_456      1
6/06       0      0      0      0  cust_456      0
6/07       0      0      0      0  cust_456      0
6/08       0      0      0      0  cust_456      0
6/01       0      0      0      0  cust_789      0
6/02       0      0      0      0  cust_789      0
6/03       0      0      0      0  cust_789      0
6/04       0      0      0      0  cust_789      0
6/05       0      0      0      0  cust_789      0
6/06       0      0      0      0  cust_789      0
6/07       0      0      0      0  cust_789      0
6/08       0      1      1      0  cust_789      1
```

should I make the target variable be something like

```
df['target_variable']='no_purchase'
for cust in list(set(df['customer'])):
  df['target_variable']=np.where(df['visit']>0,cust,df['target_variable'])
```

or have my visit feature be my target variable? If it's the latter, should I OHE all 2 million customers? If not, how should I set this up on Keras so that it classifies visits for all 2 million customers?

Comment: You want to predict whether a customer will buy something within the next two weeks; that's two classes, right? (i.e. 0 if he/she did not buy something, 1 if he/she did)

Comment: @JonathanGuymont I could use the visit feature as my target variable  but I'm not sure if I should change the target variable to be 'no_purchase' or the customer id whenever the customer buys something. If I made the visit feature my target variable(in which case I would only have two classes) should I one hot encode the customer_id column? Or would I have to make a separate model by customer_id?

Comment: One hot encoding a feature with one million categories is a bad idea; it would take a lot of memory to store very little information. If you really think the id are useful features, you should look at embeddings. Embedding is a way to learn feature representation of categorical features that are dense (as opposed to sparse in the case of one hot). Embeddings are optimized like the rest of the parameters. That means if two customers have very similar behavior, their embeddings should be very similar. Their is an implementation in Keras: https://keras.io/layers/embeddings/

Comment: @JonathanGuymont thank you for your reply. I read over the documentation. I have used word embedding before but I haven't dealt with with identifying embedding for an identifier like customer_id. I'm assuming it would learn which customers are similar? So all I would have to do is add a layer like model.add(Embedding(2000000,1,input_length=X.shape[1])) correct? How would I be able to interpret the results as far as which customer_ids will make a purchase in the next 2 weeks?

Comment: @JonathanGuymont would my loss function be binary_crossentropy since my target variable is 0 or 1 even though I'm trying to determine the visit for each customer?

Comment: Yes, binary cross-entropy is appropriate here if your targets are 0 and 1. I don`t understand *even though I'm trying to determine the visit for each customer?*; you want to make the prediction for all the customers and the ones that have a prediction 1 are the ones that bought something right?

Comment: @ Jonathan Guymont exactly, our end goal would be to find all customers that will have high probability of purchasing something in the next two weeks. So I'm going to change the structure to weekly frequencies instead of daily and time shift by 2 since we want the next 2 weeks

Comment: @Jonathan Guymont sorry to keep dragging this but what would my embedding layer look like for something like this example? I've only seen embedding used for text based projects (such as sentiment analysis). For instance, what would I pad my sequences to?

Comment: You don't need padding, you just need to choose you embeddings dimension, let's say k. Then all your user id are going to be map to a k dimension vector. This k dimension vector is then feed in the neural net along all the other features. While this could work, I would definitely start with a simpler method; at least to have baseline to benchmark your approach

Comment: @JonathanGuymont okay, I tried using an embedding layer of size Embedding(2000000, 50, name='customer_id') but I keep running into memory errors(especially once I consider 2 years worth of trips by customer). What would you recommend for that?

Answer (score 1):

I think you should better understand your problem -- your problem requires strong domain knowledge to correct model it, and it can be modeled in many different ways, and below are just some examples:

---

**Regression problem:** given a customer's purchase record only containing relative date, e.g.

- construct a sequence like [date2-date1, date3-date2, date4-date3, ...] from your data.
- [6, 7, 5, 13, ...] means a customer is likely to buy things on the weekly or biweekly basis
- [24, 30, 33, ...] means a customer is likely to buy things on the monthly basis.

If you organize problem in this way, all you need is to predict what is the next number in a given sequence. You may easily get such data by

1. randomly select a full sequence, say `[a, b, c, d, e, f, ..., z]`
2. randomly select a position to predict, say `x`
3. pick `K` (say `K=6`) proceeding sequence `[r, s, t, u, v, w]`as your network input, and `x` as your network target.

Once you have this model been trained, your ultimate task can be easily resolved by checking whether the predicted number is greater than 60.

---

**Classification problem**:  given a customer's purchase record of `K` months, predict how many purchase will a customer have in the next two month.

Again, you need to create training data from your raw data, but this time the target for a customer is how many items does he purchased in month `K+1` and `K+2`, and you may organize your input data of `K`-month record in your own way.

Please note, the number of items a customer purchased is a discrete number, but way below 1M. In fact, like in problem of face image based age estimation, people often quantilize the target into bins, e.g. 0-8, 9-16, 17-24, etc. You may do the same thing for your problem. Of course, you may also formulate this target as a regression problem to directly predict how many items.

---

Why you need to know your problem better?

- as you can see, you may come up a number of problem formulations that might all look reasonable at the first glance or very difficult for you to say which one is the best.
- it is worthy noting the dependence between a problem set-up and its hidden premise, (you may not notice such things until you think the problem carefully). For example, the regression problem set-up to predict the gap of the next purchase implies that the number of items a customer purchased does not matter. This claim may or may not be fair in your problem.
- you may come up a much simpler but more effective solution if you know your problem well.

In most of problems like yours, you don't have to use deep learning or at least not at the first place. Classic approaches may work better.

Comment: thank you for your reply. I like the suggestions you provided but all I'm trying to do is predict which customers will make a purchase in the next two weeks. I could change the frequency from days to weeks, however calculating the pairwise date difference sequences might be tricky given the 2 million customers and 2-5 years worth of transaction data for each customer. Building a model to classify whether one person will buy something next week seems straightforward. What I find confusing is how to do this for every customer